# Bind a custom control to DataGrid.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, binding

I have a UserControl in WPF that contain a textBox. My user control is placed on a WPF window. I also have a DataGrid on that window. I need to bind the text box to a property of the selected item in the dataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
        <Binding ElementName="GridId" Path="SelectedItem.Content"/>
```

Sample

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding ElementName="GridId" Path="SelectedItem.Content"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```